# C++ Metaprogramming - Create a tuple containing all variants of a templated method

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Some pseudo code as follow:

```
struct Meta
{
  std::tuple<..., ..., ...> funcVariantsTuple;

  template<typename T>
  void addVariantToTuple()
  {
    /* Do stuff */
  }
}

class A
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  void func()
  {
    Meta::addVariantToTuple<T>();
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.func<int>();
  constexpr first = std::tuple_size<decltype(Meta::funcVariantsTuple)>();
  std::cout << first << std::endl; // Prints 1                                               
  a.func<char>();
  constexpr second = std::tuple_size<decltype(Meta::funcVariantsTuple)>();
  std::cout << second << std::endl; // Prints 2                                              
}
```

The goal would be to re-define the tuple each time, but still keeping the old "stored" types which means just appending the last one.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. I'm not quite sure if I explained well but I have no idea of any other relevant thing to tell you.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: C++ is statically typed. `decltype(Meta::funcVariantsTuple)` can't magically be different at different points in the program. I strongly believe your quest is hopeless.

Comment: I'm asking if we can re-define a type during the compilation time, it is said that metaprogramming is a fully functional language, at this moment something like this would be doable but how, I have no clue.

Comment: `it is said that metaprogramming is a fully functional language` Precisely. In a fully functional language, there are no mutable variables. But you expect `Meta::funcVariantsTuple` to be such a variable.

Comment: Roger that, I'll have to find another way to do what I planned, I guess, Thank you Igor for your help.

Comment: Article of Interest: **[How to implement a compile-time meta-container in C++](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't quite work the way you think. tuples are types, not values. They are intrinsically immutable. They way to achieve what you want is to manufacture new types as the results of metafunctions involving previous types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<class Tuple = std::tuple<>>
class A
{
public:
    using tuple = Tuple;

    template<typename T>
    struct func
    {
        using type = A<decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<tuple>(), std::declval<std::tuple<T>>()))>;
    };

};
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    using a = A<>;
    using b = a::func<int>::type;
    using c = b::func<char>::type;

    constexpr auto first = tuple_size<b::tuple>();
    cout << first << endl;

    constexpr auto second = tuple_size<c::tuple>();
    cout << second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Richard, thank you for your answer, that's not quite well what I'm looking for. I think that currently C++ won't let me do what I've on my mind.